# Programmatically generating printer-friendly output

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, printing

I am creating an application (targeting 10.5 and up, but could afford to go 10.6 if needed) which contains a database of words (using Core Data). I would like to be able to allow the user to print out a sheet of card templates with different words on them- similar to flash cards.

Even just generating a printer-friendly PDF document would suffice. I just don't know where to look for this kind of thing... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already drawing these cards in a view, it should be fairly straightforward to print since Quartz uses PDF for drawing (which is why you can "Send to PDF" anywhere you can print throughout the OS).

Perhaps one of these documents can help you:

- [Printing Programming Guide for Mac](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/index.html) **(update: link changed since original post)** - I think this is what you need (especially the Cocoa Printing Architecture).  Here's an excerpt:

  > NSView generates the data to be printed. Because Cocoa drawing is device independent, a view generates print commands simply by drawing itself with regular Application Kit and Core Graphics drawing commands after the display device has been changed to a printer. A view can be told to print itself by invoking its print: method.
- [PDF Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html) - This is more if you want to generate/manipulate PDFs directly.

  > PDF Kit is a technology that allows you to display and manipulate PDF documents in your applications. By implementing aspects of Adobe’s PDF specification for you, PDF Kit minimizes development time on your part. Even Apple’s own applications such as Safari and Preview use PDF Kit to display PDF content.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm pretty new to Cocoa, so I'm actually not sure how I would go about creating these NSView objects... I'm not currently drawing them in any way other than showing the words/descriptions in a NSTableView created in Interface Builder.

Comment: `NSTableView` and all other views are subclasses of `NSView`. Because they are subclasses they inherit all the printing-related methods.

Comment: Ok I guess that makes sense, but in my case I'd like to actually have the words in a layout on a page (easy to cut into cards) rather than whatever the `NSTableView` would look like when printed (would it look exactly like how it does in the application?). I take it I need to create this new view dynamically and then print *that*...

Answer (score 0):

You could use an internet web service like [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) which means you have a lot less coding to learn/do. The downsides to that approach are that it's not free and you need to be net-connected.